# How to delete property with dynamic name of an object?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a value of prop (text input) and assigning it to the name of the property of the object, but I can't delete it;
When I am deleting it like this it refers to value of property, but not the property itself

```js
function addPr() {
  let p = prop.value;
  employees = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    [p]: {
      value: val.value
    },
  });
  console.log(employees);
  del.addEventListener("click", () => {
    delete employees[p];
    console.log(employees);
  });

}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and execution to make it a [mcve]

Comment: man you for real edited my grammar mistakes and asked to add html for this simple code? wow

Comment: Sure. Now I have to eyeball debug. If I have a [mcve] I can just run an see any errors in the console before contemplating the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [properties are not writable, enumerable or *configurable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#using_propertiesobject_argument_with_object.create), but when a property is non-configurable [it cannot be deleted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#configurable).

Just need to specify `configurable: true`:

```js
  employees = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    [p]: {
      value: val.value,
      configurable: true
    },
  });
```